# Storing value from try for use in second try C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day fellow helpers, i have following problem:
(running MS Visual Community Edition 2015)

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          // Senden
{
    serialPort2.WriteLine("SR,00,002\r\n");
    textBox1.Text = "gesendet";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    try
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\blub.txt");
        String line = file.ReadToEnd();
        string Hallo = line;   \\in the beginning there is "0" in the file
            file.Close();
        decimal counter = Convert.ToDecimal(Hallo);   \\just for testing
        counter++; 
        string b = serialPort2.ReadLine();
        string[] b1 = Regex.Split(b, "SR,00,002,"); \\cuts off unwanted input from device
        decimal b2 = decimal.Parse(b1[1]);  \\number like -3000
        System.IO.StreamWriter test = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\blub.txt");
        test.WriteLine(counter);
        test.Close();
        textBox7.Text = "Das ist counter:" + counter;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        textBox3.Text = "Timeout";
        throw;
    }

}
```

Now, the Serialport is a device that returns a lengthmeasurment. As it is a bit weird, or just the way its build it start with a negitve number (between -5000 and -3370). Now as i want to get measurement on the screen that is realistic i want to set the value to 0 and calculate the difference.

Means: I start the programm - press send - get a value (say -3000) - press send again (after pushing the seonsor in) and get the value that its been pushed in > 0 by adding the difference to 0.

I only learned to store values externally when i had a C course a year back like i did within my programm. Is there a way to store the value from the first measurement in the programm so i can use it on the next send/try?

The counter was just for testing and I would exchange it for the "decimal b2"

I hope there is an easy fix for that, not really a pro with C# yet but i'm eager to learn. I thank the willing helpers in advance, MfG, Chris

Comment: What type of C# program is this?

Comment: ah sorry, ill add this in. I use MSVisual Community editon 2105

Comment: There is a lot that could be said about above code (parameter names, using, validation, error checking, ..) , but the simple answer to your problem would be to define a property (or even a field) on class level and set that from the try block.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: is it really that bad?^^ as said im farily new to the whole thing and wanted to do something with the sensors =) i'll look into your proposal and see what i can find on that.

Comment: I believe it is WinForms. At least thats what i clicked when starting the project in MSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I will simplify this in order to show concept so it will not have all the code you are actually using.
So, what you want is to click on button, get some values and store them for next click.
Value is stored in variable. If you have variable in function that is handler for click event, as soon as function completes execution, value will be destroyed.
So, what you need is to create variable in outer scope (class level). Your function is already in class of the form so let's get to code:

```
class Form1
{
    string BetweenClickStorage;
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load data here
        BetweenClickStorage = LoadedData;
    }
}
```

After this, when you click again on the button, value will still be in `BetweenClickStorage`. It will be also available to all other buttons click handlers and other code in that form.

Comment: perfect, worked like a charm. Together with the Math.Abs i finally got some reading from the sensor =) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the answer is simply to declare a variable outside the try/catch:

```
//declare variable //
var measurement;

// TRY #1 //
try
{
    //assign value to the variable here
}
catch
{
}

// TRY #2 //
try
{
// reference variable here
}
catch
{
}
```